# select min max for group data from data table

Tags: mysql

hi i have data table like this

```
nickname  date         is_unique
test      01-01-2016   yes 
test      01-02-2016   yes 
test      01-03-2016   yes  
test1     01-01-2016   yes 
test1     01-02-2016   yes 
test1     01-03-2016   yes
```

i try to group data for display data like this

```
nickname  startdate    enddate        is_unique
test      01-01-2016   01-03-2016     yes 
test1     01-01-2016   01-03-2016     yes
```

but when i use query code min max it show just 1 column data is "test" it not show data of "test1" 
here is my sqlquery command

```
SELECT b.nickname, min(a.date), max(a.date), a.is_unique 
FROM `table1` a 
join `table2` b 
on b.fingerid = a.acno
where a.is_unique = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `GROUP BY b.nickname` in your query, like this,

```
  SELECT b.nickname, min(a.date), max(a.date), a.is_unique 
        FROM `table1` a 
        join `table2` b 
        on b.fingerid = a.acno
        where a.is_unique = 1
        GROUP BY b.nickname
```